# How to make a specific group owner in Wifi-Direct Android

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I have an Wifi Direct Android Application which will run on two Phones.

When `phone1` connects to `phone2` , I want `phone1` to act as a `client` and `phone2` to act as a `server`.

I used this code:

```
if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {

           // start the server thread

   } else if (info.groupFormed) {

            // start the client thread
   }
```

But the problem is that , sometimes `phone1` which has initiated the connection and I want it to act as a client , it sometimes acts as a `GroupOwner`, and the server thread is started on the client phone.

I want to make sure that `phone2` always act as a `GroupOwner` and a `server`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To set a peer as a client , not a `GroupOWner` eachtime , we have to assign:

```
config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;
```

Comment: What about the opposite of that? How do you force a peer to NOT be a client?

Comment: It depends upon the value which ranges between 0-15 , higher the value higher the possibility of becoming a groupOwner.

Answer (score 5):

Well, what you can do is:

```
@Override
public void connect(final WifiP2pDevice device) {
    //obtain a peer from the WifiP2pDeviceList
    WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
    config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
    config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
    config.groupOwnerIntent = 15; // I want this device to become the owner
    mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            //success logic
            Log.d(P2P, "connected to device " + device.deviceName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            //failure logic
            Log.d(P2P, "unable to establish connection to device " + device.deviceName);
        }
    });
}
```

Note the `config.groupOwnerIntent = 15;` line. This tells WifiP2pConfig that we the device stating the connection is more likely to become a GroupOwner.

Doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pConfig.html#groupOwnerIntent)

Hope it helps.